# English equivalent of Konkani proverb "kam natilo achari bhurganchi kule tasto" (When jobless, a carpenter takes to even filing children's buttocks)

Tags: phrases, idioms, proverbs

English equivalent of Konkani proverb "kam (job) natilo (not having) achari (Carpenter) bhurganchi (Children's) kule (buttocks) tasto (files)" (When jobless, a **Clueless** carpenter takes to even filing (as if with a file) children's buttocks).

**Example:**

> The rain has just stopped. In an organization where there is lot of
>   monkey business, even when there is expectation of a heavy downpour in
>   few hours, an inexperienced, inept Chairman of the company orders the
>   supervisors to engage their workers to clear the street from rainwater
>   with mops, repaint the street with traffic lines around the company,
>   etc. instead of seeing that there is no business and one should push
>   the right buttons..instead of this busy work. One can say, "When
>   jobless, a clueless carpenter takes up the stupidest stuff -- funnily
>   said as filing children's asses. The emphasis is on a clueless
>   management decision of wiping up the rain water instead of investing
>   efforts in better corrective action when your company is in ruins
>   (does not have business and/or is near bankruptcy), usually you would
>   scramble to get more business not get involved in meaningless jobs
>   especially when you know there is non-stop rain during the rainy
>   season.

Comment: When you write _assess_, do you mean _asses_ in the American sense (i.e. bottoms)? The nearest expression I can think of is 'rearranging the deckchairs on the Titanic' https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/rearrange-the-deck-chairs-on-the-titanic

Comment: yes asses = bottoms and "titanic" express is very close to the said phrase

Comment: @KateBunting But is not the Titanic example mostly used as a criticism of people who engage with the unimportant, when they should be addressing something far more serious? The Konkani proverb would seem to relate to people whose usual occupation is not available, attempting to continue with it in a ridiculous way.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Kule in konkani means tooshie. As WS2 put it, its just because one does not have any productive work which yields income does not mean one should go and do ludicrous jobs like thew saying goes that of filing someones ass aptly said for an oaf empty-suit (carpenter) thinking he is doing something meaningful. Btw there is no link to this sayings (of any of most i have ever posted previously too), much if not all are not documented as konkani, marathi being a second tier language (as they are regional) in a country of thousand of languages.

Comment: Much of this are used by older generations but still find meaning in today's world.

Comment: EDITED for clarity: Could you provide a link to a page that has the original idiom? The word "bottom" has several different meanings, it's not always a person's derriere (backside). If that is the correct meaning, I would change *asses* with something less vulgar sounding, e.g. *bottom*, *backside*, or *buttocks*.

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying -- except for "filing." Is this something a parent would normally do when the child uses the bathroom, and asks for help with wiping off (with soft paper)?  If so, I would use maybe "polishing" instead of "filing."  Filing would damage the child's tender skin.

Comment: Exactly thats the point, filing ofany sort will damage a child's tender skin and is not a thing to do. So when a carpenter is supposed to do better work instead he is said (purposely for humor sake) to do filing which is not suppose to be done on any one let alone children.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any idiom similar to "Hunger wall"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/498771/any-idiom-similar-to-hunger-wall)

Comment: The above is similar (not same) to this idiom डोळ्यात (dolyat - in eyes) केर (Ker - dust) आणि (ani -and) कानात (Kan'at - in ear) फुंकर (Fonker - blowing air) (Dust in Eyes and blowing the ears) - meaning रोग एक आणि उपचार दुसराच (illness is something, cure being done is for something else). Similarly But a idiot carpenter instead of search right job, goes around filing children's buttocks (which is meaningless work - it's a humor). Meaning situation demands  something else (productive like searching for actual job) and here you are doing something else (mostly idiotic, meaningless, useless).

Answer (score 1):

A phrase that describes this is [busy work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_work).

> Busy work (also referred to as make-work and busywork) can refer to activity that is undertaken to pass time and stay busy but in and of itself has no actual value.

This wikipedia entry has a picture of mopping outdoors, just as the OP described. The caption reads

> Chores such as mopping outdoors can be busy work.

Your sentence might read: *The inept Chairman of the company orders the supervisors to find **busy work** for their workers.*